# "the idea of consequence" or "the idea of a consequence"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, zero-article, countability

I came across a sentence in an [online dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=ICylixhKK4QC&pg=PA722&lpg=PA722&dq=%22it%20should%20be%20used%20to%20convey%20the%20idea%20of%20powerful,%20dramatic%20consequence%22&source=bl&ots=jH_Nezya69&sig=v8uMILc2KQVY8OAn0QPODQLH5ZQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGvPSN0aPaAhUG71MKHUzsCVAQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22it%20should%20be%20used%20to%20convey%20the%20idea%20of%20powerful%2C%20dramatic%20consequence%22&f=false):

> [R]ather, it should be used to convey **the idea of powerful, dramatic consequence.**

Why is it not *the idea of **a** powerful, dramatic consequence*? According to [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/consequence), **consequence** is a count noun. Shouldn't it be preceded by an indefinite article?

Comment: I did not see that on the click-through page. That said, you can say in English: that x is of consequence or x is of no consequence. Consequence can be viewed as an abstract noun like happiness, etc. It also says that. of consequence, no s. [something weird just happened, I could have sworn you had a link, which I clicked on and now I cannot find the link. Hmm]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consequence has another definition which is noncountable.  From the 
[Merriam Webster dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/consequence)

> [noncount] formal : importance or value
>
> He was a man of consequence. [=he was an important man]
>
> The outcome of the election will be of little consequence (to me). [=will not matter much to me]
>
> The style you choose is of no consequence.

Your quote above is using this definition.

Comment: Very true. Well said.